# Regard y_true and y_pred as single sample or a batch of samples in Keras.Metric?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I want to build a custom metric which can used with `model.compile`, I got confused about how to understand `y_true` and `y_pred` in the callable function. Here is an example given in the [Keras documnets](https://keras.io/api/metrics/#creating-custom-metrics).

```
def my_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)  # Note the `axis=-1`

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=[my_metric_fn])
```

From the codes, I think `y_true` and `y_pred` are batch of samples. But it also says that "Much like loss functions, any callable with signature metric_fn(y_true, y_pred) that *returns an array of losses (one of sample in the input batch)* can be passed to compile() as a metric".

Does that mean the output return in the callable is the loss for one single sample? Should we regard `y_true` and `y_pred` as single sample or batch of samples in metric/loss function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They’re batches of samples, yes.

Your function should accept two arrays, then return one of the same length. So to answer your question, regard them as batches of samples, not single samples.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So, the function returns the metric value of one batch. I see. Could you please upvote this question? So that I will get enough reputations to upvote your kindly answer.

Comment: Sure thing, just did. Glad I helped!